# Reading gpickle returns different result when migrating to networkx 2.0

Tags: migration, networkx

When migrating from networkx version 1.1 to 2.0 I have encountered an issue regarding `networkx.read_gpickle` function.

In version 1.1 the returned value is a Graph object containing `'edge'`, `'adj'` and `'node'` attributes. Whereas in version 2.0 the same function returns a Graph object containing only the `'edge'` attribute.

When calling `len(network.nodes())` the following error is produced:

```
{AttributeError}'Graph' object has no attribute '_node'
```

Is there a way to obtain obtain the `'node'` attribute as well in version 2.0?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to refactor your question and apply some code formatting.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Was the original graph pickled created in networkx version 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

For people also bumped into this problem, here is the answer from networkx github:

[networkx 1.1 vs 2.0 gpickle](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2688)

In short, it's not compatible.